# How to set decimal input range using javascript or html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input and I need it to be limited to only these values:

**Min: 0.01 max 999.99**

If I use `maxlength="6"` I can enter, for instance, `999.99` but also `1000.1` which is not an accepted value.

What I've tried:

1st attempt (not working):

```
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" maxlength="6" min="0.01" max="999.99">
```

2nd attempt (partially working):

```js
let maximumFractionDigits = 2;
const formatNumber = (value) => {
      return parseFloat(value.replace(/,/g,'')).toLocaleString('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits });
    }


$('input[name="test"]').on('keyup',function(){
    maximumFractionDigits = 2;
    if (!$(this).val() || (maximumFractionDigits && $(this).val().endsWith('.'))) {
        return
    }
    $(this).val(formatNumber($(this).val()).replace(/,/g,''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

INPUT TEST
<input type="text" maxlength="6" name="test" class="form-control">
<br>
```

With the second approach, I still can input weird numbers like `10000.` and values like `0.0X` can't be introduced (I guess it's rounded), how could I just limit the values to **Min: 0.01 max 999.99**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I found a solution:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.example');

input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  let number = e.target.value;
  number = number.toString();
  if(number.match(/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$/)){
    console.log("True");
  } else{
    const newNum = (e.target.value).toString().slice(0, -1)
    e.target.value = parseFloat(newNum);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control example" id="quantity" name="quantity" maxlength="6" min=0.01 max=999.99>
```

Hope this helps if someone has the same situation

Answer (score 1):

You can check for 3 conditions,
For first 2 convert number to string

1. The max length of the string should be 6
   `maxlength = 6`
2. If string has decimal point then .split('.') and check the length of decimal numbers
   `const decimal = input.split('.')[1]`
3. Check if the number is
   `0.01 < number < 999.99`

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you, could you provide an example?

Comment: `function validateInput (num) {
  if(num < 0.01 && num > 999.99) return false
  const strNum = num.toString();
  const strDecimal = strNum.split('.')[1]
  if(strNum.length > 6) return false
  if(strDecimal.length > 2) return false

  return true;
}

console.log(validateInput(1000.01))
`
[eg](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-grass-ozby4v?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

You have to methods to achieve the same

1. change the input type, and set min-max values:

```
<input type="number" min=0.01 max=999.99 name="test" class="form-control" aria-label="Equipment Procurement %">
```

2. If you don't want to change the type:

```
const numInput = document.querySelector(".form-control");
numInput.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  const number = parseInt(e.target.value);
  if (number > 999.99 && number < 0.01) // throw Error or do whatever you want to do
})
```

Comment: Your answer is completely wrong.

1. It's basically the same as I did without `""`, does not work. 2. Your logic is not correct, it should be `||` instead of `&&`. use `event` or `e` but don't mix both...

Answer (score 0):

you can just use step

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" />
```